# MYSQL 8.0.2.8 Information_schema character set is incorrect, and I cannot find where to change it

Tags: mysql, debian

I have a database installation where the collations look as so:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

[image]

As you can see, all the databases are utf8mb4, while the information schema is showing up as utf8mb3. This is causing me issues as I need to monitor some replication on this database using PRTG and PRTG is complaining that utf8mb3 is not accepted by .NET.

Now, I know that information_schema is a view and not a table, therefore I cannot just alter table it. I am not sure where it is getting the utfmb3

When I run :

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION, TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.tables;
```

almost everything comes up `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`, with the expected exception of some NULLs, and some utf8mb4_bin spread out here and there.

| TABLE_NAME | TABLE_COLLATION | TABLE_SCHEMA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| columns_priv | utf8_bin | mysql |
| component | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| db | utf8_bin | mysql |
| default_roles | utf8_bin | mysql |
| engine_cost | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| func | utf8_bin | mysql |
| general_log | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| global_grants | utf8_bin | mysql |
| gtid_executed | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | mysql |
| help_category | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| help_keyword | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| help_relation | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| help_topic | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| innodb_index_stats | utf8_bin | mysql |
| innodb_table_stats | utf8_bin | mysql |
| password_history | utf8_bin | mysql |
| plugin | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| procs_priv | utf8_bin | mysql |
| proxies_priv | utf8_bin | mysql |
| replication_asynchronous_connection_failover | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| replication_asynchronous_connection_failover_managed | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| replication_group_configuration_version | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | mysql |
| replication_group_member_actions | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | mysql |
| role_edges | utf8_bin | mysql |
| server_cost | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| servers | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| slave_master_info | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| slave_relay_log_info | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| slave_worker_info | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| slow_log | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| tables_priv | utf8_bin | mysql |
| time_zone | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| time_zone_leap_second | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| time_zone_name | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| time_zone_transition | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| time_zone_transition_type | utf8_general_ci | mysql |
| user | utf8_bin | mysql |
| accounts | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | performance_schema |

How can I remove all traces of utf8mb3 from the information schema?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, not here, on the programming focused SO!

Comment: I was not aware that it existed. I shall repost ASAP

Comment: See [10.9.3 The utf8 Character Set (Alias for utf8mb3)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html), [Character Set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259), [Bug #33556024 - Connector/Net doesn't recognize utf8mb3](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/commit/16ad749586b0e5eb1aad127e3744096692e4a6ae) and [MySql.Data.MySqlClient .Net Core Class Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/8.0.28).